# Why doesn't the browser send the PHPSESSID cookie from the previous request header back to the server on a second request?

Tags: php, cookies, session-cookies, php-8

It seems I don't really understand the handling of the `PHPSESSID` cookie in PHP and in browsers. I don't understand when the browser does store the cookie and send it back and when the browser doesn't store and doesn't send it back. I tried the following code with the PHP's local server: `php -S localhost:8900 ./test.php`

With the first example I get the cookie correctly on the second request. So, on the first request `print_r` prints an empty array, on the subsequent request it prints the array with the session cookie:

```php
<?php
print_r($_COOKIE);
if (!isset($_COOKIE['PHPSESSID'])) {
    session_start();
    echo "Starting a session<br/><hr/>";
}
```

After the first request: `Array ( ) Starting a session`

After the second request: `Array ( [PHPSESSID] => 4f5eh40sjlul4ggs86evee0s73 )`

---

But with the following code, I never get the `PHPSESSID` cookie in the serverside code. I can see that the server sends the cookie back in the response header, as in the first example, but the browser doesn't seem to store it and so the browser doesn't send the cookie in the second subsequent request to the server:

```php
<?php
print_r($_COOKIE);
if (!isset($_COOKIE['PHPSESSID'])) {
    session_start();
    echo "Starting a session<br/><hr/>";
}
else {
    echo "Destroying a session<br/>";
    setcookie('PHPSESSID', '', time() - 3600);
}
```

---

The problem is that I'm working on session handling on a big PHP BE and I'm trying to figure out how does the session in PHP work, especially with the `PHPSESSID` cookie.

So, I really want to understand this part of the session handling.

Comment: Calling `session_start` dependent on whether or not the `PHPSESSID` cookie already exists, makes no sense to begin with. Even if that cookie is already set - you still need to call `session_start` for PHP to pick up the session identified by that cookie's value again, otherwise you do not _have_ a session.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each request, your code alternates between setting and destroying sessions

Since you said:

> ```
> php -S localhost:8900 ./test.php
> ```

… **every** request goes through your script.

So when you type `http://localhost:8900/` into your browser's address bar it requests `/` and creates the session and then requests `/favicon.ico` and deletes the cookie. When you reload the `/` it repeats.

Comment: Ah, I got so confused with the session handling, that I overlooked it. My bad! `php -S localhost:8900` and requesting `localhost:8900/test.php` just worked. Thank you @Quentin!